# Position a div in the center of a page even if the width and height changes

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>
```

How can I position this div in the center?

Comment: http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  margin: -70px 0 0 -170px;
}
```

More you find [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

On the parent of that div:

```
div.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position the element with `top: 50%; left: 50%;` then use `translate()` to move it back/up 50% of it's own width to put it in the absolute center.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>
```